# Formview insert not working if autopostback=true. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page with a `dropdownlist` that has a `selectedIndexChanged` event attached.  So, for each option in the `dropdownlist`, there is a `usercontrol` that contains a form relevant to that section.  (each user control is in a panel, and the `selectedIndexChanged` event toggles visibility of that panel.

However, for one of the forms, I am inserting the data into SQL Server, so have used a formview, only the trouble was it wasn't inserting.

After spending ages stripping back the page to find out the point of failure, it turns out that it is the `AutoPostBack="true`" on the `dropdownlist` that is causing the problem.  Even when I remove all other panels/usercontrols, and making it so the formview panel is visible all the team (meaning that the `dropdownlist` is not changed and therefore no pastback happens) it still just fails.  If I remove that from the dropdown, the data inserts no problem.

Has anyone seen this before, or can think of a logical reason why this might be happening?

I'll post up the code of the `dropdown` just in case it helps:

```
<asp:Label ID="uxFormSwitchLabel" runat="server" Text="What would you like to do?" AssociatedControlID="uxFormSwitch" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="uxFormSwitch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="uxFormSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select" Text="Please Select" Selected="True" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="Change my address" Text="Change my address" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="Change my bank details" Text="Change my bank details" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="Change my class of use" Text="Change my class of use" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="Change my personal details" Text="Change my personal details" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="Other" Text="Other" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

UPDATE - as requested, here is the code for the formview insert:

```
<asp:FormView ID="uxDriverByID" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DriverID" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="dsDriverByID" ondatabound="uxDriverByID_DataBound" oniteminserting="uxDriverByID_ItemInserting">    
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="uxEntryType" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("EntryType") %>' />

        <asp:Label ID="uxDateLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxDate" Text="Date cover is to begin"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxDate" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>        
    <div class="clear"></div>        


        <asp:Label ID="uxEndDateLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxEndDate" Text="Date cover is to begin"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxEndDate" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="uxTitleLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxTitle" Text="Title" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxTitle" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Title") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Mr" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Mrs" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Miss" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Ms" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Doctor" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:Label ID="uxFirstNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxFirstName" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="uxSurnameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxSurname" Text="Surname"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="uxDateOfBirthLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxDay" Text="Date of birth"></asp:Label>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="dateofbirth">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="uxDay" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="uxMonth" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="uxYear" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>

        <asp:Label ID="uxGenderLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxGender" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
        <div class="input">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxGender" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Male" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Female" />
        </asp:DropDownList>  

        <asp:Label ID="uxRelationshipLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxRelationship"
            Text="Relationship to Proposer"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxRelationship" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Relationship") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Spouse" Text="Spouse" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Common law partner" Text="Common law partner" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Leasing company" Text="Leasing company" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Parent" Text="Parent" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Company" Text="Company" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Other" Text="Other" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        <div class="clear"></div>                

        <asp:Label ID="uxMaritalStatusLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxMaritalStatus" Text="Marital Status"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxMaritalStatus" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MaritalStatus") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Married" Text="Married" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Single" Text="Single" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Divorced" Text="Divorced" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Widowed" Text="Widowed" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Separated" Text="Separated" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Common Law" Text="Common Law" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Civil Partner" Text="Civil Partner" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxEmploymentStatusLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxEmploymentStatus" runat="server" Text="Employment Status"/>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxEmploymentStatus" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EmploymentStatus") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Employed" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Self Employed" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Retired" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Household Duties" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="In Full or Part-time education" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Unemployed" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Company" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="Independent Means" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="Voluntary Work" />
        </asp:DropDownList> 

            <asp:Label ID="uxOccupationLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxOccupation" runat="server" Text="Occupation" />  
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxOccupation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Occupation") %>'  />  

            <asp:Label ID="uxBusinessLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxBusiness" runat="server" Text="Employer's business" />  
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxBusiness" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Business") %>' />


            <asp:Label ID="uxSecondaryEmploymentLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxSecondaryEmployment" Text="Does this driver have a second occupation?"></asp:Label>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="uxSecondaryEmployment" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Label ID="uxSecondaryEmploymentStatusLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxSecondaryEmploymentStatus" runat="server" Text="Secondary Employment Status" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxSecondaryEmploymentStatus" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SecondaryEmploymentStatus") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Employed" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Self Employed" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Retired" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Household Duties" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="In Full or Part-time education" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Unemployed" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Company" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="Independent Means" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="Voluntary Work" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Label ID="uxSecondaryOccupationLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxSecondaryOccupation" runat="server" Text="Secondary occupation" />  
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxSecondaryOccupation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SecondaryOccupation") %>' />

            <asp:Label ID="uxSecondaryBusinessLabel" AssociatedControlID="uxSecondaryBusiness" runat="server" Text="Employer's business" />  
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxSecondaryBusiness" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SecondaryBusiness") %>' /> 

        <asp:Label ID="uxLicenceTypeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxLicenceType" Text="What type of licence does the driver hold?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxLicenceType" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LicenceType") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Full(UK)" Text="Full(UK)" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Provisional(UK)" Text="Provisional(UK)" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Foreign" Text="Foreign" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Restricted less than 3 years" Text="Restricted less than 3 years" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Restricted 3 years or over" Text="Restricted 3 years or over" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxTimeHeldLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxTimeHeld" Text="How many years has the driver held this licence?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxTimeHeld" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TimeHeld") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="9 or over" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxClassSelectLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxClassSelect" Text="What class of use do you want to change to?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxClassSelect" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassSelect") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select" Text="Please Select" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="SDP - Includes Commuting if Required" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Business Use Policy Holder In Person" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Business Use Spouse In Person" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="usiness Use Policy Holder and Spouse" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Policy Holder Business - Authorised Drivers" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Commercial Travelling" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxConvictionsLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxConvictions" Text="Has this driver had any motoring convictions in the last 5 years?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxConvictions" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Convictions") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:Label ID="uxClaimsLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxClaims" Text="Has this driver had any motoring claims in the last 5 years?"></asp:Label>
        <div class="input">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxClaims" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Claims") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:Label ID="uxResidentLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxResident" Text="How many years has this driver been a permanent UK resident?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxResident" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Resident") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="9 or over" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxHowOftenLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxHowOften" Text="How often will this driver use the vehicle?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxHowOften" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("HowOften") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Not Main User (frequent)" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Main User" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Infrequent (casual)" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxHomeownerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxHomeowner" Text="Is this driver a homeowner?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxHomeowner" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Homeowner") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxNumOfCarsLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxNumOfCars" Text="Does this driver have access to any other cars within the household?" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxNumOfCars" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("NumOfCars") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="9 or over" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div class="clear"></div>    

        <asp:Label ID="uxCarsOwnedLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxCarsOwned" Text="Does this driver own any other cars?" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxCarsOwned" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CarsOwned") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="9 or over" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div class="clear"></div>    

        <asp:Label ID="uxClaimFreeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxClaimFree" Text="How many claim free years of driving other cars does this driver have" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxClaimFree" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClaimFree") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="9 or over" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div class="clear"></div>  

        <asp:Label ID="uxRefusedLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxRefused" Text="Has this driver ever had insurance refused, cancelled, premiums increased, or conditions imposed?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="uxRefused" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Refused") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxOtherConvictionsLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxOtherConvictions" Text="Has this driver ever had any non-motoring criminal convictions or prosecutions pending?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxOtherConvictions" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OtherConvictions") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="uxDisabilityLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxDisability" Text="Does this driver have any disability or medical condition that could affect their fitness to drive?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxDisability" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Disability") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            </asp:DropDownList> 

        <asp:Label ID="uxSubmitLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="uxSubmit" Text="Submit"></asp:Label>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="uxSubmit" runat="server" style="float:left" Text="Submit"  CssClass="blue-button-ctrl med"
                ValidationGroup="AddDriver" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Insert" OnClick="uxSubmit_Click"  />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="uxUpdateButton" style="float:left" Text="Save changes" 
            runat="server" CssClass="blue-button-ctrl" Visible="false"
            ValidationGroup="AddDriver" CausesValidation="true"  />
        <div class="clear"></div>   

    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsDriverByID" runat="server" InsertMethod="DriverInsert" SelectMethod="GetByDriverID" 
    TypeName="GreenHomeDAL.DriverTableAdapters.DriverTableAdapter">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DriverType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SessionID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Surname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateOfBirth" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Relationship" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MaritalStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EmploymentStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Occupation" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Business" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SecondaryEmploymentStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SecondaryOccupation" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SecondaryBusiness" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LicenceType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TimeHeld" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassSelect" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Convictions" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Claims" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Resident" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HowOften" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Homeowner" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NumOfCars" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CarsOwned" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClaimFree" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Refused" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OtherConvictions" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Disability" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DriverSession" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EntryType" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

And the c# side:

 protected void PopulateDateFields()
        {
            int startYear = 1900;
            DropDownList uxDay = (DropDownList)uxDriverByID.FindControl("uxDay");
            DropDownList uxMonth = (DropDownList)uxDriverByID.FindControl("uxMonth");
            DropDownList uxYear = (DropDownList)uxDriverByID.FindControl("uxYear");

            uxYear.Items.Clear();
            uxMonth.Items.Clear();
            uxDay.Items.Clear();
            ListItem dayItem = new ListItem("DD", "0");
            ListItem monthItem = new ListItem("MM", "0");
            ListItem yearItem = new ListItem("YYYY", "0");
            uxDay.Items.Add(dayItem);
            uxMonth.Items.Add(monthItem);
            uxYear.Items.Add(yearItem);
            for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year - 15); i >= startYear; i--)
            {
                uxYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                string num = i.ToString();
                if (num.Length == 1)
                    num = "0" + num;
                string month = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[i];
                uxMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(month, num));
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                string num = i.ToString();
                if (num.Length == 1)
                    num = "0" + num;
                uxDay.Items.Add(new ListItem(num, num));
            }
            uxDay.DataTextField = "Day";
            uxDay.DataValueField = "Day";
            uxMonth.DataTextField = "Month";
            uxMonth.DataValueField = "Month";
            uxYear.DataTextField = "Year";
            uxYear.DataValueField = "Year";
        }
```

I did plan to have code in the ItemInserting event, but it only goes into that with autopostback set to false, so nothing in it yet.

Thanks

Comment: Is any data even being posted to the server? Place a breakpoint in the Submit() code that your button triggers. This way, you can ensure that the problem isnt further down the stack of your application. Let us know the results.

Comment: Ok, it hits the breakpoint in the Submit_Click event and the controls all have data even with autopostback=true.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Please post the markup and code for the `FormView` and associated datasource and/or event handlers which you expect to execute to perform the Insert.

Comment: That is the formview code added now in the original post..

Comment: Right, if I remove all options from the `DropDownList` then it works with autopostback.  As soon as I add a ListItem, it stops working.  Thought that info might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Completely unrelated answer in the end, and quite baffling really.

I have a loading gif next to the autopostback dropdownlist, which in the CSS, is set as:

```
#loading_gif{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

in the javascript, I've got this function:

```
function showLoading(id)
{    
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    setTimeout('document.images["loading-gif"].src="Assets/Images/eee-loader.gif"', 50); 
}
```

When I changed it to `display:block` and `display:none`, instead of `visibility`, the formview insert works perfectly.
Ah well it's fixed.  If anyone can shed any light on why that might happen then great, but as long as it's working then I'm happy.  Thanks